# How to Find Item in Dictionary Collection?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have declared and populated the following collection.

```
protected static Dictionary<string, string> _tags;
```

Now I want to look locate a particular entry in the collection. I tried the following.

```
thisTag = _tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == tag);
if (thisTag != default(KeyValuePair<string, string>))
    ...
```

And I get the error:

> Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair' and ''

Initially I attempted to compare the result to `null`, and I guess that's not supported with `struct`s.

I would've thought that finding an item within a collection is a very trivial task. So how the heck to I determine if the item I'm looking for was found?

(Note: I'm using `Dictionary` because I want fast lookups. I know I can use `Contains()` to determine if the item is there. But that means a total of two lookups, which sort of defeats the purpose of having a fast lookup. I'll happily using a different collection if it can quickly lookup an item and I have a way to determine if it was successful.)

Comment: So you want to solve two lookups with o(1) by performing a single search with o(n)?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
thisTag = _tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == tag);
```

This is an inefficient and a little bit strange way to find something by key in a Dictionary. Looking things up for a Key is the basic function of a Dictionary.

But the key has to exist. The basic safe solution, but one that requires 2 lookups, would be:

```
if (_tags.ContainsKey(tag)) { string myValue = _tags[tag]; /* use myValue */ }
```

### Recommended

`bool TryGetValue(key, out value)` is more concise and efficient, it only does 1 lookup. And that answers the last part of your question, the best way to do a lookup is:

```
string myValue;
if (_tags.TryGetValue(tag, out myValue)) { /* use myValue */ }
```

---

VS 2017 update, for C# 7 and beyond we can declare the result variable inline:

```
if (_tags.TryGetValue(tag, out string myValue))
{
    // use myValue;
}
// use myValue, still in scope, null if not found
```

Comment: Well, the first answer is not satisfactory. But you're right about `TryGetValue()` and I've used that before. I guess the problem was that I started with a `List<>` collection and switched it to `Dictionary<>` while still having a `List<>` mindset.

Comment: I believe there is a typo, it should be `if (_tags.TryGetValue(tag, out myValue)) { ... }` instead of  `TryGetValue(_tags, ...)`.

Comment: Another 2.5 years later and it is still helping people out.

Comment: Options are always good.  Thanks for also including the new VS 2017 syntax. +1

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes you still need to use FirstOrDefault if you have to do different tests.
If the Key component of your dictionnary is nullable, you can do this:

```
thisTag = _tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key.SubString(1,1) == 'a');
if(thisTag.Key != null) { ... }
```

Using FirstOrDefault, the returned KeyValuePair's key and value will both be null if no match is found.

Comment: KeyValuePair<T,U> cannot be compared with null.

Comment: That's not what I'm doing. I'm comparing KeyValuePair.Key with null. With this method, the Key needs to be of a nullable type.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to find the element in Dictionary collection by using ContainsKey or TryGetValue as follows:

```
class Program
{
    protected static Dictionary<string, string> _tags = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strValue;

        _tags.Add("101", "C#");
        _tags.Add("102", "ASP.NET");

        if (_tags.ContainsKey("101"))
        {
            strValue = _tags["101"];
            Console.WriteLine(strValue);
        }

        if (_tags.TryGetValue("101", out strValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(strValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you want to make sure it's in there otherwise fail then this works:

thisTag = _tags[key];

NOTE: This will fail if the key,value pair does not exists but sometimes that is exactly what you want.
This way you can catch it and do something about the error.
I would only do this if I am certain that the key,value pair is or should be in the dictionary and if not I want it to know about it via the throw.

Comment: Developers should use better terms than "fail". This word really says nothing about what it does. And what it does using your approach if the key does not exist is throw an exception, which is exactly what I was trying to avoid here. Thrown exceptions are a horribly inefficient way to determine that something doesn't exist in a dictionary.