# How to lookup / check a dictionary value by key

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to confirm whether a specific dictionary key contains a value

e.g.

does dict01 contain the phrase "testing" in the "tester" key

At the moment I am having to iterate through the dictionary using KeyPair, which I don't want to have to do as it wasting performance

Comment: You can get the value via dict01["tester"] and then do a .Contains on the value part.  Is there something I'm missing?  If you know the specific key, get its value and then simply search that string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Find Item in Dictionary Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531042/how-to-find-item-in-dictionary-collection)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) and [string.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx):

```
var key = "tester";
var val = "testing";
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(key) && myDictionary[key].Contains(val)) 
{
    // "tester" key exists and contains "testing" value
}
```

You can also use [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx):

```
var key = "tester";
var val = "testing";
var dicVal = string.Empty;
if(myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out dicVal) && dicVal.contains(val)) 
{
    // "tester" key exists and contains "testing" value
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem a good way of going about it, as your not linking the two (key and value) together, what if I wanted to search for a specific pattern in a key value - but only in one key

Comment: Using `TryGetValue` would be more efficient.

Comment: @Also, how would it be possible to lookup the actual key value - rather than checking it?

Comment: @user1559618 check `TryGetValue` example, it loads value into `dicVal` variable

Comment: @des I would have thought jobInformation["ID"].Value would work

Comment: Well, if it is `string` or `int` etc then it should be `jobInformation["ID"]` without `.Value`

Comment: When you use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` then `dictionary[key]` will return element of type `TValue`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following method if you don't want to iterate through the dictionary twice

```
string value;
var result = dict01.TryGetValue("tester", out value) && value.Contains("testing");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (myDict.ContainsKey("tester"))
    // Do something?
```

[More on MSDN](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGkQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx&ei=iy8VUMrEM6j34QTf5oGwDw&usg=AFQjCNG5GA_lnHiZsKX8RWGowcf1VMlbwQ&sig2=O7GgSJb_1eJMv6ctFrrTdg)