# Searching a String in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, string, linq, dictionary

I have this Class Form1.cs where I created my GUI, It also has a combobox with following functionality:

```
string SelectedItemName = (string)comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(SelectedItemName);
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    testvariabel2.GetSessionName();
}
```

So I check if the user has chose something from the ComboBox and than I call the Function GetSessionName in my other Class CTestRack.cs.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>>();

foreach (SectionData section  in data.Sections)
{
    var keyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (KeyData key in section.Keys)
        keyDictionary.Add(key.KeyName.ToString(), key.Value.ToString());

    newDictionary.Add(section.SectionName.ToString(), keyDictionary);

    if (newDictionary.ContainsKey(testvariabel.SelectedItemName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", keyDictionary[testvariabel.SelectedItemName]);
    }
    else Console.WriteLine("Couldn't check Selected Name");
}
```

Here I'd like to check if the String SelectedItemName exists in my Dictionary, but I always get the Systen.ArgumentNullException that the String SelectedItemName is NULL in my CTestRackClass.

Now my question, how do I search the dictionary in CTestRack for the String setted in the other Class 
Form1 ?

Comment: look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5531058/3326331)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... actually you got the looking into the dictionary right ! To find out if a key is present in a dictionary, you use `ContainsKey`.

```
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
{
    //do something
}
```

However, your problems comes from the fact that null is never a valid key in a dictionary (mainly because null doesn't have a proper hash code). So you need to ensure that the key you're looking for is not null. From your code, I guess that `testvariabel.SelectedItemName` has not been set as it should.

Moreover there is a more efficient way to look if a value is present before doing something with it. Use `TryGetValue`:

```
TValue val;
if(myDictionary.TryGetValue(myKey, out val))
{
    //do something with val
}
```

That way you don't need to access myDictionary[myKey]. If you use `ContainsKey`, you are in fact accessing the same value twice. That a small cost in most cases, but very easy to avoid, so you should give it a try.

Note that I answered only the specific question about looking into a dictionary. I cannot say anything about the correctness of your code as a whole.

Comment: I know that null is not a valid key, I have also written down the code how I set the variable SelectedItemName: "string SelectedItemName = (string)comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();"

Do you think it's wrongly settled? Because normally I would like to make the TryGetValue using the String SelectedItemName

Comment: `string SelectedItemName = (string)comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();` does not set the property `testvariabel.SelectedItemName`, it creates a new variable that you don't seem to be using afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

I see there are two clear issues with your code.

1. You are checking if a key exists in one dictionary (newDictionary) but trying to retrieve it from another (keyDictionary )
2. You are try to look up keys in the dictionary even before it's completely built. Move the if check outside of foreach loop.